# AsyncTask.execute() runs callback after onDestroy is called

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, android-asynctask, activity-lifecycle

I am saving data on `onPause` method to `SQLite` database.

- I call `myObject.saveEntry(data)`.
- It saves data by calling `AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable(){})`
- Once data is saved, the callback method `savedSuccess(message)` is called
- An `Activity` method `showMessage(message)` is called
- A toast is shown saying the data is saved successfully

My doubt is on how to handle the orientation changes. When the orientation changes,

- `onPause` is called and `saveEntry` method is called.
- After that `onDestroy` is called
- A **new instance** of the Activity is created again.
- The `savedSuccess(message)` method callback gets executed now (which was called from the previous instance of the Activity)
- `showMessage(message)` is called and toast is shown

My questions are

1. **Should I stop the `AsyncTask` from executing in the `onDestroy` method**
2. **If not, how should I handle such situations when Activity gets destroyed before the database save/update/delete is complete?**

Comment: Learn about and use a Loader instead.  They will survive the activity lifecycle if you code it propertly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is memory leaking - the AsyncTask retains a reference to the Activity it was declared in and is preventing the Android runtime from garbage collecting it. To answer your questions:

1. AsyncTask cannot be stopped with a command. You can request to cancel it in onDestroy() but it will still do it only after the doInBackground() method has executed which in your case will be the Runnable.
2. You have the option of using a static nested AsyncTask which will not hold a reference to the Activity it resides in - the caveat is that you will not be able to reference anything from the Activity but that shouldn't be a big problem for your case.

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTask within the activity may not be the best solution for running the background task, as it holds a reference to the activity, which is now destroyed.

You could consider using a Fragment with setRetainInstance(true) to do your background work with an AsyncTask, or an IntentService.

See [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) for how to use a task fragment to do your background work.

Answer (score 1):

An `AsyncTask` can survive orientation changes if you put it in a retained fragment.  See [Handling Configuration Changes with Fragments](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html).  If you want the task to survive when the activity finishes or goes into the backstack, put it in a `Service`.